# openRawResource NullPointerException

Tags: android, xml, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to parse some xml and i'm getting a `NullPointerException` but i can't seem to figure out what i did wrong:

```
    private Puzzle XMLfromFile(int xml) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

    SAXParserFactory spf= SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
    XMLHandler theHandler= new XMLHandler();
    xr.setContentHandler(theHandler);
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(xml);
    xr.parse(new InputSource(is)); //this crashes the program with the null pointer

    return theHandler.currentPuzzle;
}
```

and the caller:

```
try {
        thePuzzle=XMLfromFile(R.raw.puzzle1);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i need to sleep over my problems a little more often, i found out that a code snipit i deleted cause my handler to throw the null pointer problem. Thanks you, and again sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an integer into the `InputSource()`.  You would have to get the entire XML file as string (`getString(int id)`), or some other method of retrieving the file.

Comment: Its actually passing through a stream .openRawResource(xml) is supposed to open a raw resource as stream data for the associated resource. I tried get string anyhow, and it gives me cant convert string into inputstream

Comment: Where exactly is the NullPointerException being thrown.  Could you post the stack trace?